# Create Composite Diagram Using the Automation Interface

Tags: enterprise-architect

I need to use the EA Automation Interface from Java to create some diagrams in EA - something for which there are examples. However I also want to make some of the diagrams composite diagrams linked to an element in the model.

In EA itself it's just a question of right clicking on the element, selecting Add and then Select Composite Diagram but I can't see anywhere in the Automation Interface where I can create this relationship.

Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Element.IsComposite` is read/write. Setting it to 1 will create a composite diagram of the appropriate type, unless the element already contains one (in which case that will become the composite diagram).

`Element.CompositeDiagram`, on the other hand, is read-only. So you can't first create a diagram in some arbitrary location in the model and then set the element to point to it.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question but I stumbled upon it.

In EA v 13.0 Element.SetCompositeDiagram() was introduced and solves this question!

**myElement.SetCompositeDiagram(DiagramGUID)**